# How to deploy Angular 2 application onto Windows Server 2016

Tags: angular, deployment, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to deploy an Angular 2 application to Windows Server 2016. I followed along in this video to get the server setup to handle angular applications:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUYCDnqR8p0

Everything went smoothly.

Now I'm trying to deploy our full Angular application and it's not working. I'm told I can take the contents of the dist folder and simply drop it onto the server in the root folder of the website. Here's the dist folder on my development machine:

[image]

I copy and paste this as-is directly into the root folder on the server. The root folder also contains an iisnode folder and node_modules folder. I then create the following web.config file and save it to the root folder on the server:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

    <!-- indicates that the server.js file is a node.js application to be handled by the iisnode module -->
    <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="server/server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="sendToNode">
                <match url="/*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="server/server.js" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But this is what I get when I navigate to the site on the server:

[image]

It says it cannot find module 'compression'. I'm not sure what that is or how to make it available.

Comment: Does it really have to be node running inside IIS? - After running `ng build` you only have static files inside your `dist` folder

Comment: When posting XML/HTML, please use the preview window to ensure it has rendered - it was missing here because it had not been formatted. The formatting tool is accessed via the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

i thinK IIS is a better choice right?
just get all you have in dist folder and put them in to a new site

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaWi5.jpg)

this will work fine for me this far.

Comment: Are you kidding? Do you even know how angular works?